# Performance issue alloc vs copy

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a table view with custom cells. Each cell has images and text and they are listening notifications. Anyone knows if it would be better to have a cell allocated as a template in memory and then copy the base layout from that instead allocating a new instance every time i need to create a cell? I have to test that but I'm lazy :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` doesn't implement the `NSCopying` protocol, so you'd have to implement that yourself in a custom subclass. So if you're going to wind up writing your own implementation of `-copyWithZone:`, the question is how would that code be more efficient than whatever it is you're currently doing?

Comment: Yeah, I think I will have to test that and compare both versions. I need to improve the performance of my implementation that involves several things to do. I just had a thought about this while I am redesigning it and I decided to ask before try it. I will be back with my conclusions.

Comment: I have tried the mutableCopyWithZone but It needs to allocate the new object. Nothing better than I already have. At least in my case I have no advantages to make a copy instead allocating. I have got better results by creating just the visible cells and then, after the view is visible,  the others.

Comment: `-mutableCopyWithZone:` would be the wrong API, but as I said, I don't see how that would improve performance in any case. By the way, is this a plain or grouped style table view?

Comment: it's a plain table for a chat roster. I'm agree with you about the performance by using copy. I needed a mutable copy because the elements within the cell might change along the time. I had a significant improvement by loading cells in background while the app is loading another stuff. So, when I have the view created I don't need to create those cell. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Before you create your cell you should call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` on your `UITableView` and check if it's `nil`. If it is, create your new cell with `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`. Make sure your reuse identifier is the same for all your cells assuming they all have the same layout. That is the standard way Apple prescribes for dealing with this issue you describe.

Take a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for further details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my problem is on the creation of the cell. I already have the cells created before render the table view, so I just return the element that matchs with the index on my array.